# lldb debug java process. skip EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: macos, java-native-interface, exc-bad-access, lldb

I tried to make debugger not stop on signals:
`proc hand -p true -s false SIGBUS`
`proc hand -p true -s false SIGSEGV`

I even tried to set `-s false` on all signals.
But it still stops the execution on `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.
And it happens very often, sometimes maybe in infinite loop. It makes debugging impossible.

[image]

Is there a way to make lldb not stop on this?

Answer (score 5):

This is a long-standing bug.  The problem is that the OS mechanism whereby the Mach exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS gets converted to a SIGSEGV is not available when running under the debugger, so you just get stuck re-running the bad access, but since there's no signal raised, your handler doesn't get a chance to handle it.

Comment: Anyway to work around this? There are programs causing such bad accesses on purpose (e.g. JVM null checks) and this makes running them through the debugger impossible.

Comment: @zakkak i have not found solution for this, but i unmarked this answer as accepted so you can try to continue discussion and maybe assign bounty if you like